# How to do {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, assets, laravel-blade, lumen

In Lumen, I can do this in my blade template:

```
{{ url('/css/app.css') }}
```

In Laravel I could do

```
{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}
```

Is the url helper all I have to work with in Lumen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have look at [Lumen UrlGenerator source code](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.0/src/Routing/UrlGenerator.php), the Lumen framework supports just `url` and `route` helpers. Of course, you can write the `asset` helper if you want.

Answer (score 16):

Had the same problem, moving from laravel to lumen. As @hieu-le says, I made an asset helper as below.

```
if (!function_exists('urlGenerator')) {
    /**
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator
     */
    function urlGenerator() {
        return new \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\UrlGenerator(app());
    }
}

if (!function_exists('asset')) {
    /**
     * @param $path
     * @param bool $secured
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secured = false) {
        return urlGenerator()->asset($path, $secured);
    }
}
```

Comment: how and where I add this file to lumen?

Comment: You can create an asset helper through creating your own php file with the methods included. Then, in composer, add this: ```{
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "path/to/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
}```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Turns out Lumen has a singleton method for handling such. Just use:

```
{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}
```

or
For handling routes

```
{{ URL::route('home') }}
```