# Lumen - Generate fully-qualified url for an asset ex image - While running tests - phpunit tests/Controllers/FilesControllerTest.php

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am very new to Lumen.

I have path `public/profile/pic.png`

I want to generate url for this pic and save that url into databse.

I tried function `url(public/profile/pic.png)`. Its creating as `http://public/profile/pic.png`. Not the correct url.

I tried `asset(public/profile/pic.png)`

Error - `Call to undefined function asset`.
I tried adding UrlGenerator class. But it says class not found.

I am struck here. Please can anyone help me.

EDIT:
For me even url() is not working correctly. Its not creating correct url. `http://public/profile/pic.png`. Domain name is not getting added.
And also - I tried adding UrlGenerator class. But it says class not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} in Lumen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250112/how-to-do-asset-css-app-css-in-lumen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, while testing on Lumen, server domain name is not used.
That is the reason when url() was not working.