# How to link css files to my html in Lumen

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, lumen

I have just begun learning lumen and can't seem to find the answer to this simple question. This is my current `<head>`:

```
   <head>
    <title>Sharp notes!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
```

This causes the following error:

```
[Sat Jun 17 20:13:09 2017] 127.0.0.1:56950 [200]: /
[Sat Jun 17 20:13:09 2017] 127.0.0.1:56952 [404]: /assets/css/main.css - No such file or directory
```

Please help!

Comment: what's your route for `/` and your css path.

Comment: `/` goes to my welcome page which is in `myApp/resources/views/welcome.blade.php`. And my css path is `myApp/resources/assets/css/main.css`

Comment: `../assets/css/main.css`

Comment: Yep didn't work.

Comment: `{{ url('../assets/css/main.css') }}`

Comment: Didn't work either.

Comment: is your file .blade.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146976/discussion-between-kris-roofe-and-vineet-kaushik).

Answer (score 3):

You should put the css files in your public directory.

```
myApp/public/css/main.css
```

Then the asset helper should resolve the path correctly

```
{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}
```

Further explanation here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/asset-vs-url

Your assets (css, js, images, etc.) need to be placed in the application's public directory.

Answer (score 3):

The solution : you need to  use   **url('')** ,

Because Lumen does not provide the asset helper function you may want to use url e.g.

> The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path:
>   Blade. More informations ir : [Laravel Helpers url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url)

**HOW TO :**

With Blade :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('/assets/css/main.css') }}">
```

With PHP :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php url('/assets/css/main.css') ?>">
```

if you want you can create your own asset helper function of course, have a look here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/extend-helper-functions-to-lumen?page=0

or

[How to do {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} in Lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250112/how-to-do-asset-css-app-css-in-lumen)

Comment: edited for mistake ;) and  negative review ... I m Junior Sorry :)

Comment: With PHP you missed **echo**. It should have been;




`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo url('/assets/css/main.css') ?>">`

Comment: This is right! -> Lumen does not provide the asset helper function... worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it helps you try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('resources/assets/css/main.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your assets folder (containing img, libs, js and styles) into public folder & do the needful like like this.
`<img src="assets/img/visa.PNG">`

Answer (score 0):

In laravel lumen you don't have to define the public path . Put your assets into public folder and rest will automatically tracked.
 For more information visit https://lumen.laravel.com