# How do i import libraries in a blade file on lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, import, laravel-blade, lumen

So i have this php.blade view that i want return with lumen.

layout.blade.php

```
    <head>
    <!--AXIOS-->

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

     <!--JQUERY-->

     <script src="{{ asset("libraries/go-debug.js") }}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset("libraries/jquery-3.2.1.min.js") }}"></script>



     <!--MATERIALIZE-->

     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("libraries/materialize/css/materialize.min.css") }}"  media="screen,projection"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("libraries/materialize/js/materialize.min.js") }}"></script>

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

     <!--ICONE MATERIALIZE-->

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

     <!--CSS IMPORTATO-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("loginPage/login.css") }}">


    @yield('head')

    </head>

     <body>
           @yield('body')
     </body>
    </html>
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('imports')
    <title>Login Page</title>
@stop

@section('body')
    <script src="{{ asset("loginPage/login.js") }}"></script>
    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Logo</a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:36px;">home</i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m2" id="center">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="image/logo.jpg" class="responsive-img" id="logo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
              <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
              I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
              <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@stop
```

In this view as you can see im trying to import libraries like materialize ,css and js scripts.

The problem is that lumen cannot find this files in his path and they cannot even be called via internet.

Here's a pic of the path

[image]

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, all the **resources** must be inside the **public** folder.

e.g.

***public/js/libraries/jquery-3.2.1.min.js***

After that you move them, you change your code as per follow:

**layout.blade.php**

```
<script src="{{ asset("js/libraries/jquery-3.2.1.min.js") }}"></script>
```

---

*NB, in your case you have to move under public:*

- libraries
- bootstrap
- loginpage

---

If instead, you have your own scss or js to compile have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix

**EDIT**

Lumen does not provide the **asset** helper function you may want to use **url**
e.g.

```
<script src="{{ url("js/libraries/jquery-3.2.1.min.js") }}"></script>
```

if you want you can create your own asset helper function of course, have a look here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/extend-helper-functions-to-lumen?page=0

or

[How to do {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} in Lumen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250112/how-to-do-asset-css-app-css-in-lumen)

Comment: It gives me an error. Call to undefined function asset()

Comment: Can you show me your new blade file updating your answer please?

Comment: Thanks so much the function url works greatfully.So url helper is all I need with lumen to import files?

Comment: Glad that it helps. Honestly I don't know lumen but in laravel you need the helper "asset" in order to load files. Anyway to answer your question, yes, you just need that